# Call Enter event on keypress javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which validates the mobile number of maximum of 10 digits, and I am using input `type="text"` because `minlength` wont work on `type="number"` but the problem is when i am trying to submit form on click of keyboard enter, it is not submitting

```js
$('#welcome_submit').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    data: $('#entry_form').serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error: error");
    },
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="entry_form">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="form-class" name="phone_no" autocomplete="off" autofocus maxlength="10" />
  <button id="welcome_submit" class="btn btn-continue welcome_first" type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas of filtering the Enter event '13' in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the keycode 13 and submit the form:

```
if (evt.keyCode == '13') {
  document.querySelector('#welcome_submit').click();
}
```

```js
$('#welcome_submit').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    data: $('#entry_form').serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error: error");
    },
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == '13') {
      document.querySelector('#welcome_submit').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="entry_form">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="form-class" name="phone_no" autocomplete="off" autofocus maxlength="10" />
  <button id="welcome_submit" class="btn btn-continue welcome_first" type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @charankumar Changed it so that the button gets clicked that calls your ajax. Should work now.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the *submit* event on the form instead of listening to the *keyup/keypress* events on the input:

```js
$('#entry_form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
  // Ajax request ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="entry_form">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="form-class" name="phone_no" autocomplete="off" autofocus maxlength="10" />
  <button id="welcome_submit" class="btn btn-continue welcome_first" type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```